# How to build a guava LoadingCache with case insensitive String keys

Tags: java, caching, guava

I'm looking to make use of a guava loading cache, defined so far as follows. I would like the keys used as a string to be case insensitive. Ideally, I would prefer the cache to handle this, rather than callers needing to set the key to lowercase before using the cache, is that at all possible?

```
LoadingCache<String, MyObject>> myCache = 
    CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .build(new CacheLoader<>() {
            @Override
            public MyObject load(final String key) {
                return myMethod(key);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can use the decorator pattern by decorating your LoadingCache by a class (the decorator) which converts the lookup keys into lowercase before delegating to the underlying LoadingCache. The problem is, for this, you have to override almost all the methods in the `Cache` interface and convert the key/keys in the argument to lowercase before calling the delegate

Comment: In the above mentioned approach, you also have to think about how methods like `getAll(Iterable<? extends String> keys)` work when called with input like `["aa", "AA"]`. Should the returned map have one entry or two?

Comment: Alternatively, if correctness is more important than memory usage, consider storing your keys in Guava [`Equivalence.Wrapper`](https://guava.dev/releases/32.1.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html)s (or a custom version) that delegates equality to [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).